# StaggeredGridView is undefined

Tags: flutter, mobile-application

import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart'; //import libray

flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.5.0 // package

```
    Flexible(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, right: 16.0, left: 16.0),
        child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          itemCount: products.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => ProductPage(product: products[index]))),
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: RadialGradient(
                        colors: [
                          Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                          Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.7),
                        ],
                        center: Alignment(0, 0),
                        radius: 0.6,
                        focal: Alignment(0, 0),
                        focalRadius: 0.1),
                  ),
                  child: Hero(
                      tag: products[index].image,
                      child: Image.asset(products[index].image))),
            ),
          ),
          staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
              StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 3 : 2),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Error:

lib/screens/main/components/recommended_list.dart:51:20: Error: The getter 'StaggeredGridView' isn't defined for the class 'RecommendedList'.

- 'RecommendedList' is from 'package:mobi_zilla/screens/main/components/recommended_list.dart' ('lib/screens/main/components/recommended_list.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'StaggeredGridView'.
  child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  lib/screens/main/components/recommended_list.dart:79:19: Error: The getter 'StaggeredTile' isn't defined for the class 'RecommendedList'.
- 'RecommendedList' is from 'package:mobi_zilla/screens/main/components/recommended_list.dart' ('lib/screens/main/components/recommended_list.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'StaggeredTile'.
  StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 3 : 2),
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use Version:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
```

Answer (score 4):

The pub.dev documentation for the plugin doesn't suggest anything about the method being deprecated or scrapped in the latest version i.e `flutter_staggered_grid_view 0.6.1`. I tried using flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0 but that didn't work either. The workaround seems to be to use version `0.3.1` which then recognized the `StaggeredGridView` method.

Comment: flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0  worked for me

Answer (score 3):

The **flutter_staggered_grid_view** was completely rewritten in its  version **0.5.0-dev.1** update.
You can now use **StaggeredView** to display a staggered view.

**Example**

```
StaggeredGrid.count(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4,
  children: const [
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 2,
      mainAxisCellCount: 2,
      child: Tile(index: 0),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 2,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 1),
    ),
  ],
);
```

**Solutions:**
As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view-library.html#classes), you can use **StaggeredGrid**  instead of StaggeredGridView to display a staggered view.
Alternately, you can revert back to older versions of the package as already mentioned.
**Note: StaggeredGridView is  still supported in version 0.4.0**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the latest version of `flutter_staggered_grid_view` can not use `StaggeredGridView.countBuilder` instead you have to use `GridView.custom` like this, it will work like charm

```
GridView.custom(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 16.w,
                left: 16.w,
                right: 16.w,
              ),
              gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
                crossAxisCount: 6,
                mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
                pattern: const [
                  QuiltedGridTile(4, 4),
                  QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
                  QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
                ],
              ),
              childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                return Container(...)
              }, 
               childCount: your_list_length
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

StaggeredGridView.countBuilder is not working
package is alerady install import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).